# Custom ArrayAdapter filtering

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Can somebody tell why nothing changed on screen when i'm using filter. Under debug i can see that here:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mFilteredEmployeeItems = (ArrayList<EmployeeItem>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

mFilteredEmployeeItems has correct filtered count of elements, but after notifyDataSetChanged() nothing changed on screen.

Here is my full code:

```
public class EmployeesFragment extends Fragment {    
    private static final int item_Header = 0;
    private static final int item_Employee = 1;

    public static class EmployeeItem {
        private int mItemType;
        private String mGUID;
        private String mName;
        private String mCardID;

        public EmployeeItem(int AItemType, String AGUID, String AName, String ACardID) {
            mItemType = AItemType;
            mGUID = AGUID;
            mName = AName;
            mCardID = ACardID;
        }

        public int getItemType() {
            return mItemType;
        }

        public String getGUID() {
            return mGUID;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return mName;
        }

        public String getCardID() {
            return mCardID;
        }
    }

    private class EmployeeItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EmployeeItem> implements Filterable {

        public EmployeeItemsAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.groupheader_empty, mFilteredEmployeeItems);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            EmployeeItem vEmployeeItem = getItem(position);

            switch (vEmployeeItem.getItemType()) {
                case item_Header:
                    if (vEmployeeItem.getName().equals("")) {
                        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.groupheader_empty, null);
                    } else {
                        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.groupheader_text, null);
                    }

                    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_txt)).setText(vEmployeeItem.getName());

                    break;

                case item_Employee:
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.universallist_item, null);
                    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.UniversalItem_CaptionTxt)).setText(vEmployeeItem.getName());

                    break;
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                    mFilteredEmployeeItems = (ArrayList<EmployeeItem>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    ArrayList<EmployeeItem> FilteredArrayNames = new ArrayList<EmployeeItem>();

                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                        results.count = mFullEmployeeItems.size();
                        results.values = mFullEmployeeItems;
                    } else {
                        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mFullEmployeeItems.size(); i++) {
                            EmployeeItem dataNames = mFullEmployeeItems.get(i);
                            if (dataNames.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                                FilteredArrayNames.add(dataNames);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    results.count = FilteredArrayNames.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrayNames;

                    return results;
                }
            };

            return filter;
        }
    }

    public EmployeesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private static View mRootView;
    private List<EmployeeItem> mFullEmployeeItems = new ArrayList<EmployeeItem>();
    private List<EmployeeItem> mFilteredEmployeeItems = new ArrayList<EmployeeItem>();
    private ArrayAdapter<EmployeeItem> mAdapter;
    private int mPosition;
    private EditText mSearch;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employees, container, false);

        mAdapter = null;
        doGenerateFormElements();

        mSearch = (EditText) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.search_edt);
        mSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString().trim());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        return mRootView;
    }

    private void doGenerateFormElements() {
        String vSQLText;
        switch (AppCommon.mActualCardAction) {
            case AppCommon.C_CardAction_Remove:
                vSQLText = "select EmployeeGUID, EmployeeName, CardID from TempEmployeesList where (CardID <> '') order by EmployeeName;";
                break;

            default:
                vSQLText = "select EmployeeGUID, EmployeeName, CardID from TempEmployeesList order by EmployeeName;";
                break;
        }

        mFullEmployeeItems.clear();
        mFilteredEmployeeItems.clear();

        mFullEmployeeItems.add(new EmployeeItem(item_Header, "", "", ""));
        mFilteredEmployeeItems.add(new EmployeeItem(item_Header, "", "", ""));
        SQLiteDatabase vSQLiteDatabase = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
        Cursor vCursor = null;
        try {
            vCursor = AppCommon.SQLite_SelectRecords(vSQLiteDatabase, vSQLText);
            if (vCursor.getCount() != 0) {
                do {
                    mFullEmployeeItems.add(new EmployeeItem(item_Employee,
                                                        AppCommon.Cursor_GetValueAsString(vCursor, AppCommon.Fld_EmployeeGUID),
                                                        AppCommon.Cursor_GetValueAsString(vCursor, AppCommon.Fld_EmployeeName),
                                                        AppCommon.Cursor_GetValueAsString(vCursor, AppCommon.Fld_CardID)));

                    mFilteredEmployeeItems.add(new EmployeeItem(item_Employee,
                                                            AppCommon.Cursor_GetValueAsString(vCursor, AppCommon.Fld_EmployeeGUID),
                                                            AppCommon.Cursor_GetValueAsString(vCursor, AppCommon.Fld_EmployeeName),
                                                            AppCommon.Cursor_GetValueAsString(vCursor, AppCommon.Fld_CardID)));
                } while (vCursor.moveToNext());

                //mFilteredEmployeeItems = mFullEmployeeItems;
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException sqle) {
            Log.e("Employees", "doGenerateFormElements error: " + sqle.toString());
        } finally {
            if (vCursor != null) {
                vCursor.close();
            }

            DatabaseManager.getInstance().closeDatabase();
        }

        doRefreshAdapterContent();
    }

    private void doRefreshAdapterContent() {
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new EmployeeItemsAdapter(mRootView.getContext());
            ListView listView = (ListView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.Employees_List);
            //Here i analyse items OnClick

            listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: no need for a custom `Filter`, just override `EmployeeItem#toString`

Comment: Can you please show small example?

Comment: example of a custom `@Override public String toString() { return ...;}` ?

Comment: Sorry. Not clear hot to use it instead filter

Comment: wait, are those employees taken from sqlitdb? if so, just use `SimpleCursorAdapter` and if you want filterning setup its `FilterQueryProvider`, you will be surprised how it shorten your code...